# single line if statement

Tags: javascript

please help me. I am using a single line javascript if statement, but i want it to execute two actions after it has checked the condition but i do not know how to put the second statement. I thought a semicolon will work, but it doesn't. it says the semicolon is an error.
here is my code, with the semicolons...

```
this.className === "unclickedButton" ? this.className = "clickedButton";
 $("#alert").style.display="block" : this.className = "unclickedButton"; 
$("#alert").style.display="none"
```

Comment: Why can't you just use a regular `if` statement?

Answer (score 7):

You *can* do this, using the [comma operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.14):

```
this.className === "unclickedButton" ?
(this.className = ($("#alert").style.display="block", "clickedButton")) :
(this.className = ($("#alert").style.display="none", "unclickedButton"));
```

...but it wouldn't say it makes for readable code. I'd use a normal `if`.

Here's a [live example](http://jsbin.com/ekecax/1) using jQuery ([source](http://jsbin.com/ekecax/1/edit)). (I used `show` and `hide`, see below). But seriously, compare that for maintainability/readability to:

```
if (this.className === "unclickedButton") {
    this.className = "clickedButton";
    $("#alert").style.display = "block";
}
else {
    this.className = "unclickedButton";
    $("#alert").style.display = "none";
}
```

I know which one I'd rather do maintenance on. Or if you want a one-liner, change the CSS slightly so you have a `button` class and a `clicked` class you *add* to it, and do this (I'm assuming jQuery here):

```
$("#alert").toggle($(this).toggleClass('clicked').hasClass('clicked'));
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/ekecax/3) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ekecax/3/edit)

---

Side note: The selectors you're using look like what you'd use with jQuery, but jQuery instances don't have a `style` property. If you're using Prototype or MooTools, you probably want to remove the `#` in front of `alert`. If you're using jQuery, use its `show` and `hide` methods (and probably `addClass` / `removeClass`).

Comment: This works because of the assignment on each line, but unfortunately `$("#alert").style.display =` is ineffective, though you could use the hideous `$("#alert")[0].style.display = ` to go along with the rest of the hideousness.

Comment: @ExplosionPills: LOL, I was just flagging up in the answer that those lines look strange, not quite a match for either jQuery nor Prototype or MooTools. *Could* be some other library, but it seems doubtful...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder whenever unstated, I assume jQuery.

Comment: thank you very much guys, i ended up using all your advices and i ended up with this line of code and it is now working...............  newContent += createButtons(item.CommonCable, "unclickedButton", "submit", item.CommonCable, 'this.className === "unclickedButton"?(this.className = ($("#alert")[0].style.display="block", "clickedButton")):(this.className = ($("#alert")[0].style.display="none", "unclickedButton"))');

Answer (score 0):

Try do it by dwo if statement like this:

```
    if(statement 1){
        ...
        if(statement 2){
        ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm afraid the asker won't like this solution

Comment: What would be those two statements, by the way? I can only think of one.